# checking for palindromes in js

Tags: javascript

I have been doing tasks in freeCodeCamp and I'm stuck with checking for palindromes. Can anyone help me with this? 
I have pasted my code here :

```
function palindrome(str) {
  // Good luck!
  return true;
}
```

palindrome("eye");

Comment: You've forgotten to paste what you've tried?

Comment: @pwolaq A top catch for a dup! `<sarcasm>` I hope OP can really use it, considering the function name is different.`</sarcasm>`.